# Normal Subgroups proof help

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

This is what I have so far.

proof: Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$. Let $h$ be in $H$ and $g$ in $G$. Then $ghg^{-1} = hgg^{-1}$ since $H$ is a subgroup of $Z(G)$. Then $hgg^{-1} = h$ which is in $H$. Thus $h$ is in $Z(G)$. So $ghg^{-1}$ is in $H$. Then $ghg^{-1} = h$. Now by right cancellation, $gh = hg$. Hence, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: In your proof, since ghg^-1 belongs to H. H is normal. Seems legit to me.

Comment: Too many words, @michelley: stop right after "Then $\;ghg^{-1}\stackrel{\text{since H$\,\le\,$ Z(G) !}}=hgg^{-1}=h\in H\;$ " . That's enough to prove normality

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be an element of $g$.
Then $aH=Ha$ (as all elements of $H$ commute, as subset of $Z(G)$).

Answer (score 1):

You actually went too far! $ghg^{-1} = hgg^{-1} = h\in H$ is enough, by the [Normality Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normal_Subgroup_Test).